# VS2010 Build Log File is Incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-2010, logging, incredibuild

My VS2010 C++ project, release config, has an Output Directory of:

`$(SolutionDir)\..\_build\Release\`

The Intermediate Directory is:

`$(SolutionDir)\..\_build\Release\Obj\$(TargetName)\`

The Build Log File is just the **default** setting:

`$(IntDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName).log`

However, the build log file is not being written where I expect it to be. It is instead being written to:

`$(SolutionDir)\_build\Release\Obj\$(TargetName)\$(MSBuildProjectName).log`

It's as if the `..` is being stripped from the path when writing the log file. However, *all* other intermediate files are written to the correct directory.

Is the log writer altering my path? It seems to be 90% correct, but it's missing a vital `..`. Is there anything I need to do to get it to read correctly?

---

#### Update:

After playing around with it, I've discovered that **IncrediBuild** is causing the problem. Building without IncrediBuild puts the log file in the correct place, but with IncrediBuild the log file is going into the wrong directory.

Comment: I cannot comment yet so I decide to post as an answer... I have the exact same issue, and I do have the Incredibuild installed. However, removing Incredibuild is not helping. The "..\" part is still stripped. Is this a bug with the <BuildLog> tag?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<Path>$(SolutionDir)..\Output\$(ProjectName).log</Path>
```

It works for me. SolutionDir already has a `\` on the end so you end up with `\\` in the path, which I think is the problem.

Comment: I have the same conclusion `$(*Dir)..` works, while `$(*Dir)\..` messes up. (Visual Studio 2013 Express)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, say if I want to put the log file in the Output folder that is one level higher than the current solution file location, like this:

```
MyTestProject
    |___ MyTestProject.sln
    |___ MyTestProjectFolder
    |___ Debug
Output
    |___ MyTestProject.log
```

In the vs 2010 project file, instead of using:

```
<BuildLog>
  <Path>$(SolutionDir)\..\Output\$(ProjectName).log</Path>
</BuildLog>
```

I have to use:

```
<BuildLog>
  <Path>$(SolutionDir)\..\..\Output\$(ProjectName).log</Path>
</BuildLog>
```

This is a little bit weird because I don't have to use 2 ".." for all the other paths, like OutDir and IntDir. I will update this answer if I find anything further.